# Custom scope in CDI seems to require beans.xml

Tags: cdi, custom-scope

I created a custom scope in CDI.

```
@NormalScope(passivating = false)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) @Target({ElementType.TYPE,ElementType.METHOD,ElementType.FIELD})
@Inherited
public @interface MyScope { }
```

It works only if I had `beans.xml` with in my deployment. Is this a must?

Comment: What CDI version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have packed custom scope as separate jar and placed beans.xml inside. Now its working fine.